# How to use a closing backtick followed by an alphabet in AsciiDoc

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

If a closing backtick(`) is followed by an alphabet, it's not rendered as expected.

For example, `Link`s will be rendered just `Link`s not `Link`s.

Using `{empty}` solves the problem like `Link`{empty}s` but it's quite ugly.

Any better way to achieve this?

UPDATED:

I'm using `asciidoctor-gradle-plugin`.

A simple sample project is as follows:

https://github.com/izeye/samples-spring-boot-branches/tree/asciidoctor

Answer (score 1):

I think your workaround is the best that we have currently, but this does seem like a case that was missed in the tests. It's an issue apparently: https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor/issues/1514

Answer (score 0):

use the escape character before the s. like this \s

http://www.methods.co.nz/asciidoc/faq.html#_how_can_i_escape_asciidoc_markup

Comment: Sorry but I already tried it and didn't work. I updated my question to have a sample project to show it.